# How do I use Django REST Framework GIS to query GeoJSON

Tags: api, geodjango, rest, django

I am trying to write the view that will return a GeoJSON of my model stored in the database. I would like to create an API so that I can use an AJAX request in a JavaScript file I have. I have not been able to find how to use the Django REST Framework GIS serializers in my views. I simply want to create an API that returns the GeoJSON to load in my Leaflet map.

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from .serializers import GeoJsonSerializer
from .models import UtmZones
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'proj_picker/proj.html', context)

def api_get_utm(request):
    utm_poly = serialize('geojson', UtmZones.objects.all(), geometry_field='mpoly')
    return JsonResponse(utm_poly, safe=False)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

# Create your models here.
class UtmZones(models.Model):
    swlon = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    swlat = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    hemisphere = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    zone = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    cm = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    zone_hemi = models.CharField(max_length=5)

    mpoly = models.MultiPolygonField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.zone
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='proj'),
    path('api/utm/', views.api_get_utm, name='utm'),
]
```

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: PostgreSQL with PostGIS extension.

Comment: it seems like you need to add the `api_get_utm` to the urls.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to do it with Django 2.2's serializer so I didn't need DRF-gis. My problem was the JsonResponse was unecessary because I had already serialized it as a json. The following code works.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import UtmZones

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'proj_picker/proj.html', context)

def api_get_utm(request):
    utm_poly = serialize('geojson', UtmZones.objects.all(), geometry_field='mpoly', fields=('zone', 'zone_hemi'))
    return HttpResponse(utm_poly, content_type='application/json')
```

Answer (score 0):

your workflow looks fine but give my below query a try

```
def api_get_utm(request):
   cur = conn.cursor()
   qry='''SELECT row_to_json(fc)
          FROM
           ( SELECT 'FeatureCollection' AS TYPE,
                   array_to_json(array_agg(f)) AS features
           FROM
             (SELECT 'Feature' AS TYPE,
                     ST_AsGeoJSON(g.geom,4326)::JSON AS geometry,
                     row_to_json(
                                   (SELECT p
                                    FROM
                                      ( SELECT "INSERT FIELD NAMES") AS p)) AS properties
              FROM "TABLE NAME" AS g
              ) AS f) AS fc;
      '''
   cur.execute(qry)
   row=cur.fetchone()
   return JsonResponse(row[0])
```